# SSL configuration on confidential part of store on front end

Tags: checkout, ssl

I have an issue in my website I want to enable the https on confidential part of front end like checkout, login, register etc I make the configuration like this in backend

[image]

but https is not enabling on confidential part of store I create some model for secure checkout found on google but still didn't work. if I change the unsecure base url to https it apply on whole site which I don't want.

Kindly any body can help me in this issue..

Comment: why don't you want the ssl on all the site? There are a log of good reasons as to why such as higher rankings in google, better security.

Comment: actually client don't want that and also it slow down the site i need to enable https if customer buy something or login to account or register

Comment: Your issue at custom module ? am i right?

Comment: yes i am using custom module and using the eros theme